# fgetcsv throwing error when calling from CLI

Tags: php, cron, fgetcsv

Can run my php file fine when checking it via browser, but throws an infinite loop error when run via CLI:

**fgetcsv() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given on line 30 (while line)**

Code:

```
readCSV("feeds/data.csv");
function readCSV($csvFile) {
    $count = 0; //for counting array objects
    $storedQuotes = array();
    $handle = fopen($csvFile, 'r');
    //fgetcsv($file, 1000, ","); //remove first line

    while (($line = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {

       $quote = $line[2];
       $author = $line[1];

    //add element to $csv_arr with $quote and  $author
        $csv_arr[]=array(
                        "quote"    =>    $quote,
                        "author"    =>    $author
                    );
}

fclose($file);
}
```

How can I get my program to run via php cli?

Comment: Check path to csv file and it's existence

Comment: Parses fine via web page call. File is there.

Comment: "Parses fine via web page call" doesn't mean anything. Flush that from your brain and look at the problem. $handle is most likely "false", indicating an error. File not found. Permission problem. etc... Focus on the problem and you have a shot at finding a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check if `$handle` is a resource (or is false) first. For example:

```
$handle = fopen($csvFile, 'r');
if(false !=== $handle) {
  // do while{} here
}
else {
  echo "Could not open $csvFile for reading";
}
```

Also, in CLI, your file paths are different. So you need to be more explicit. The easiest way to do this, if `$csvFile` is located in a relative path to the script, is to define the path such as:

`__DIR__ . "feeds/data.csv"`

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your PHP code doesn't find the file (because fopen returns false).

I think you should use full path instead of relative since you are running it in cmd.

You should set your path like the following:

```
readcsv(dirname(__FILE__).'/feeds/data.csv');
```

It should work if "feeds" directory is in the same directory as your PHP file.